# PWM in ANSYS Twinbuilder software

Tags: inverter, matlab, powermosfet, pmsm

Where can I learn PWM Control stratergies for MOSFET using algorithms in an inverter, in ANSYS Twinbuilder software? I also want to get familiarised with ANSYS interface.